# factorization of $a^3 + b^3$ over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves

I have been trying to understand how to factorize a basic $a^3 + b^3$  over $\mathbb{C}$. I saw in the book that it is $ \Pi_{i=1}^{3}(a + \omega^{(2i+1)}b)$ where $\omega$ is the cuberoot of  $-1$.

I was trying to derive it in the following way and was surprised by something which I cannot explain. $a^3 + b^3 = (a^3 - (\omega b)^3)$, I tried to use the formula for factorization of $a^3 - b^3$. Since we know $a^3 - b^3 = (a-b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$ hence I was trying to factorize  the original expression as $a^3 -(\omega b)^3 = (a - \omega b)(a^2 + \omega ab + (\omega b)^2)$.

Then using $ 1 + \omega + \omega^2 = 0$. I substituted $(a -\omega b)(a^2 -(1 + \omega^2) ab + (\omega b)^2) $. This is factored as $(a -\omega b)(a - \omega ^2 b ) (a - b) $. This when expanded is $ (a^2 - \omega^2 ab - \omega ab + \omega^3 b^2) = (a^2 + ab - b^2) (a -b)$. Surely this product does not give back the original expression.

Which assumption am I misunderstanding during substitution which is creating this problem is unclear.

Comment: Do you wish to find $a^3+b^3$ or $a^3-b^3$?

Comment: I want to find $a^3  + b^3$  using the formula of $a^3 - b^3$. If u use $\omega^3 = -1$ then it should be equivalent,.

Comment: $1+\omega+\omega^2 = 1$ not 0.

Comment: Sorry, meant 2, not one.

Comment: $\omega ^3$ is 1 and not -1.and $\omega^2+\omega = -1$

Comment: Thank u @safdar, that clears up the problem. I think the mistake I made was confusing the two $\omega^3 = 1$ and $\zeta^3 = -1$

Comment: @Safdar But it is a cube root of -1, as defined by the OP. By definition, $\omega^3=-1$. The issue is that $1+\omega+\omega^2 = 2$, not zero.

Comment: @BobbyOcean Perhaps you meant $1+\omega + \omega^2 = 2\omega$?

Comment: Ya, i miscalculated, $2\omega$ is what wolframalpha gets. My main point was that it is not zero.

Comment: $a^3-b^3$ is the product of $a-\xi b$ with $\xi$ ranging over the set of solutions of $\xi^3=1$. With $a^3+b^3$ the factors are $a-\xi b$ with $\xi$ ranging over the set of solutions of $\xi^3=-1$. That is, the negatives of the cube roots of unity.

Comment: Note that the factorising $a^3 + b^3$ is the same as computing the three solutions of $a^3 = -b^3$, namely $a = -b, a= -\zeta b$ and $a = -\zeta^2 b$, with $\zeta^3 = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what our OP user2714795 is trying to do, but here's my approach:

Does

$a^3 + b^3 = (a + b)(a^2 - ab + b^2)? \tag 1$

we compute

$(a + b)(a^2 - ab + b^2)$
$= a^3 - a^2b + ab^2 + a^2b - ab^2 + b^3 = a^3 + b^3, \tag 2$

so yes, (1) binds.  We also have

$(a + b\omega)(a + b \bar \omega) = a^2 + ab (\omega + \bar \omega) + b^2 \omega \bar \omega \tag 3$

for any

$\omega \in \Bbb C; \tag 4$

if we take

$\omega = -\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2}i \tag 5$

then (3) becomes

$(a + b\omega)(a + b \bar \omega)$
$= a^2 + ab (\omega + \bar \omega) + b^2 \omega \bar \omega = a^2 - ab + b^2;  \tag 6$

combining (1) and (6) yields

$a^3 + b^3 = (a + b)(a + b\omega)(a + b\bar \omega), \tag 7$

and we have factored $a^3 + b^3$ over $\Bbb C$.